# Scrollview animation not smooth (objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, scrollview

I am trying to scroll my scroll view up when the textFieldDidBeginEditing delegate method is called.  It works, but there is one buggy issue.  On the FIRST call of the method (when the user taps the textview for the FIRST time, the animation is not smooth, and instantaneous jumps to the topPoint.  Every animation afterwards is smooth.  Why is the first animation not smooth like the other ones?  Am I missing something?

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGPoint topPoint;
    topPoint = CGPointMake(0, 200);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:topPoint animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only happens when the debugger is plugged in.  It even causes audio glitches too, I lost hours toiling over it and even filed a radar for no reason :|